# how to configure android Volley to use OKhttp

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am trying out the Volley networking library
i would like to switch to using the OKhttp jar with volley
i just cannot work out how to configure volley to use this alternative http provider.
what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out jake wharton's  `HttpStack` implementation for Volley that uses OkHttp as its transport.

https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5616899

Comment: Quality (and so simple), not just fjords you excel at then?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use and OkHttpStack like [this one](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750) that does not use okhttp-urlconnection.

I've written an [article about using OkHttp, Volley and Gson](https://medium.com/@sotti/android-networking-i-okhttp-volley-and-gson-72004efff196) for Android networking that you might find interesting.